# Getting map markers from Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the coordinates of the database, and with those coordinates a marker is placed in the exact place.

**My database:**

[image: Picture of my database]

**My code:**

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
DatabaseReference f_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    f_database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("profile").getChildren()) {
                String rightLocation = child.child("lat").getValue().toString();
                String leftLocation = child.child("lng").getValue().toString();

                double location_left = Double.parseDouble(leftLocation);
                double location_right = Double.parseDouble(rightLocation);
                LatLng cod = new LatLng(location_left, location_right);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title("pedik"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer

```
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ 
   String lat = child.child("profile").child("lat").getValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: Friend, i need get coordinates from all users, not only my user

Comment: child.child("profile").child("lat") returns a `DatabaseReference`. To return a String you need to add `.getValue(String.class)`.